# JAVA KeyEvent serialization error

Tags: java, oop, serialization, client-server, keyevent

I am trying to send an object that contains a `KeyEvent` field through a socket object output stream, the javadoc says that `KeyEvent` is implementing the `Serializable` interface, but whenever I try to send it throws a `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

The object I am trying to send is `KeyboardCommand`

```
import java.awt.Robot;

public interface ICommandAction {
void doAction(Robot operator);
public enum ActionType {GenericAction, MouseAction, KeyboardAction, CheckBooleanAction};
ActionType getAction();
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CommandBase implements Serializable, ICommandAction{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
private ActionType action;

public CommandBase(ActionType action){
    this.action = action;
}

public ActionType getAction(){
    return this.action;
}

public void doAction(Robot operator){
    try {
        operator.wait(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyboardCommand extends CommandBase {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8L;
private KeyEvent event;

public KeyboardCommand(KeyEvent event) {
    super(ActionType.KeyboardAction);
    this.event = event;
}

/**
 * Presses and releases the event's key 
 */
public void key(Robot operator, int delay){
    operator.keyPress(event.getExtendedKeyCode());
    operator.delay(delay);
    operator.keyRelease(event.getExtendedKeyCode());
}

/**
 * Performs the keyboard action
 */
@Override
public void doAction(Robot operator){
    boolean isUpperCase = Character.isUpperCase(event.getKeyChar());
    if(isUpperCase) operator.keyPress(KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
    key(operator, 20);
    if(isUpperCase) operator.keyRelease(KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
    System.out.println("Keyboard command executed");
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "KeyCode: " + this.event.getKeyCode() + ", keyChar: " + this.event.getKeyChar();
}        
}
```

---

```
public synchronized void sendCommand(CommandBase command){
    try {
        commandOutputStream.writeObject(command); //error is here
        commandOutputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("Sent " + command.getAction().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to send " + command.getAction().toString());
        try {
            commandOutputStream.close();
            running = false;
            this.dispose();
            System.out.println("Closing command output stream");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqyME.png)

The error is on the `commandOutputStream.writeObject(command)` line, which means it can't serialize on the senders' side.

From what I can tell everything should be `Serializable`, if anyone knows where I messed up your help is appreciated :)

Miniature example: (The `KeyboardCommand` is the same)

```
public class Constants {
final static int senderPort = 20000; 
final static int receiverPort = 20001;
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import commands.CommandBase;
import commands.KeyboardCommand;

public class ControlFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener, Runnable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 12L;
private Socket sendAction;
private ObjectOutputStream commandOutputStream; 

public boolean running;

public ControlFrame(Socket socket){
    super("Controller");
    this.running = true;

    this.sendAction = socket;

    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 2, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height / 2);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    try {
        this.commandOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(sendAction.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Command output stream initialized");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Command output stream failed to initialize");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public synchronized void sendCommand(CommandBase command){
    try {
        commandOutputStream.writeObject(command);
        commandOutputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("Sent " + command.getAction().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to send " + command.getAction().toString());
        try {
            commandOutputStream.close();
            running = false;
            this.dispose();
            System.out.println("Closing command output stream");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key typed");
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key pressed");
    System.out.println("Key command: " + e.toString());
    sendCommand(new KeyboardCommand(e));
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key released");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    addKeyListener(this);

    while(running){
        if(sendAction.isOutputShutdown())
            running = false;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import commands.CommandBase;
import commands.ICommandAction.ActionType;
import commands.KeyboardCommand;

public class Receiver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, AWTException {

    ServerSocket acceptConnection = new ServerSocket(Constants.receiverPort);
    Socket receiver = acceptConnection.accept();

    ObjectInputStream receiverInput = new ObjectInputStream(receiver.getInputStream());
    Robot operator = new Robot();

    while(true){
        Object command = receiverInput.readObject();
        if(((CommandBase)command).getAction().equals(ActionType.KeyboardAction)){
            ((KeyboardCommand)command).doAction(operator);
        }
    }
}

}
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import FrameResources.ControlFrame;

public class Sender {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final InetAddress thisIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    Socket sender = new Socket();
    sender.bind(new InetSocketAddress(thisIP, Constants.senderPort));

    sender.connect(new InetSocketAddress(thisIP, Constants.receiverPort));

    ControlFrame frame = new ControlFrame(sender);
}
}
```

In this example the same error happens.

IF anything is unclear just comment the question.

Thank you for your time :D

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels good idea, added imports and error message

Comment: Thank you but please post the error as code-formatted text, and please indicate which line(s) are involved (as the stacktrace will tell you)

Comment: Please post the code that you use to serialize.

Comment: Indeed -- the error is coming from the ControlFrame class, and I don't even see you posting this class's code.

Comment: @POrekhov I am not explicitly implementing `Serializable`, i am using the default methods because all of the objects the class contains are serializable.

Comment: You're not even posting the right code

Comment: @OE.omergunr100 no, i am asking for the code that serializes, and not the code that makes your objects serializable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added the method where the error happens

Comment: @OE.omergunr100 I have tried to reproduce your error and do not get any exceptions. You should just post your entire code, because this is still not enough.

Comment: Or better, a [mcve] extraction of your code.

Comment: Links to code base is not allowed per site rules as this is a Question and Answer site, not a help site per se. You're going to want to create a smaller version of your program, a [mcve], one that compiles, runs, and that demonstrates the error, and post that code here in your question as code-formatted text. Please check out the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok thank you for the warning, i am going to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the KeyEvent is the cause, possibly because it contains reference to the source object, your JFrame, a complex object which might contain both serializable and non-serializable fields.... But you don't really need this information, and so an obvious solution comes to mind -- don't serialize KeyEvent but rather serialize and de-serialize the key information that KeyEvent contains, the keyCode, keyChar, and extendedKeyCode fields. For example, note changes:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class KeyboardCommand extends CommandBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8L;
    // private KeyEvent event;
    private char keyChar;
    private int keyCode;
    private int extendedKeyCode;

    public KeyboardCommand(KeyEvent event) {
        super(ActionType.KeyboardAction);
        // this.event = event;
        keyChar = event.getKeyChar();
        keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        extendedKeyCode = event.getExtendedKeyCode();
    }

    /**
     * Presses and releases the event's key
     */
    public void key(Robot operator, int delay) {
        // operator.keyPress(event.getExtendedKeyCode());
        operator.keyPress(extendedKeyCode);
        operator.delay(delay);
        // operator.keyRelease(event.getExtendedKeyCode());
        operator.keyRelease(extendedKeyCode);
    }

    /**
     * Performs the keyboard action
     */
    @Override
    public void doAction(Robot operator) {
        // boolean isUpperCase = Character.isUpperCase(event.getKeyChar());
        boolean isUpperCase = Character.isUpperCase(keyChar);
        if (isUpperCase)
            operator.keyPress(KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
        key(operator, 20);
        if (isUpperCase)
            operator.keyRelease(KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
        System.out.println("Keyboard command executed");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // return "KeyCode: " + this.event.getKeyCode() + ", keyChar: " + this.event.getKeyChar();
        return "KeyCode: " + keyCode + ", keyChar: " + keyChar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I am a student and this is my side project, I was really discouraged by this annoying error, but now I can continue, btw the project is about remote controlling a computer

Comment: @OE.omergunr100: thank you for your attempts to improve the question

Comment: btw I love Autoit too

Comment: @OE.omergunr100: yes, it's a very handy and powerful utility, but I wish it were object-oriented

Comment: Maybe, but as of right now it's still very useful in automating repetitive tasks, and if you use color or image matching it can even make small decisions based on changes on screen